# 200 Buttons All Changing One TextBox - VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, button

I have a VBA Excel application with about 200ish buttons. I want them all to change one textbox called "Name" with the caption of the button pressed. I did blur some stuff from the image as these boxes are all real peoples name. How can I do this without having to create 200+ functions?

An example is let's say I have 3 buttons. The three values are `foo1`, `foo2`, and `foo3`. When I click any of the buttons, let's say I click `foo2`, I want the TextBox to update the value to `foo2`. I know how to do this but how do I do it without having to manually write a function for all 3 buttons. The textbox value will always be the button value. Now imagine it is 200+ buttons.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I'd approach it.  First add a class module and call it `buttonClass`:

```
Option Explicit

    Public WithEvents aCommandButton As msforms.CommandButton

    Private Sub aCommandButton_Click()
         MsgBox aCommandButton.Name & " was clicked"
    End Sub
```

Then in your userform initiation event, use code similar to:

```
Dim myButtons() As buttonClass

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ctl As Object, pointer As Long
        ReDim myButtons(1 To Me.Controls.Count)

            For Each ctl In Me.Controls
                If TypeName(ctl) = "CommandButton" Then
                    pointer = pointer + 1
                    Set myButtons(pointer) = New buttonClass
                    Set myButtons(pointer).aCommandButton = ctl
                End If
            Next ctl

        ReDim Preserve myButtons(1 To pointer)

End Sub
```

This will wire up all of your command buttons to display their name on click.  You can tweak the logic in the buttonClass to be fancier.  Or you can tweak the logic in the initialize event to include on certain buttons (expanding on the "If" part).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Should my buttons be a certian name?

Comment: I have two users forms and I only want the buttons on the second one to take effect.

Comment: you only need to give your buttons a certain name IF you want to subset them somehow.  The current code will add *all* command buttons on the form to a single event.

Comment: also, the collection is limited to the scope of the form.  So you should be good.

Comment: Great I will try!

Comment: great! let me know how it turns out and we'll go from there :)

Comment: how would I switch from userform1 to userform2 with the click of a button?

Comment: When running your code I get `compile error: user-defined type not defined`. What should I do. I put the class in a class module and your code in my userform2 @sous2817

Comment: And know it is vba

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150858/discussion-between-sous2817-and-brendan).

Comment: the class module must be manually renamed ButtonClass, or it wont´t work. Go left it the property window of the class in vbe, and change the name property.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow.  The code I posted works just fine, but if changing to to upper case works for you, that's all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

If i was going to do this (and I'm not sure I would), I would create and populate each button through a loop, which also set up a link to one event handler which could determine what to do.

If each button is created manually and already exist, then I think you need to update them manually.

Another possibility, is to catch another higher-level event such as mouse click and then, from the information provided by that event, work out which button was pressed.